# How can an absolute value equation with a variable have both a positive, and negative answer?

Tags: absolute-value

I thought absolute values are supposed to be a number's distance from 0, which is always positive. So I had this equation:

> | 7 – y | = 12

According to practice tests they say this,

> This equation means we need to solve two equations: **7–y=12**, and **7–y=-12** which means **y=-5,19**.

Even if the answer inside the vertical bars was negative, wouldn't the vertical bars make it positive, resulting in just 1 positive answer?

Thanks for any help you can give!

### Edit

I found out what happened! I didn't notice when they said the equations could have both 12, and -12 they didn't include absolute value bars, so they were just referring to how the variable can be both positive, or negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite.

Recall that
$$|y| = \begin{cases}y,&\text{if } y\geq 0\\-y,&\text{if } y<0\end{cases}$$

Notice that the problem asks for all values $y$ **such that** 
$$|7-y| = 12.\tag 1$$
If $y = -5$, then
$$|7-(-5)| = |7+5| = |12| = 12.$$
Further, if $y = 19$, then
$$|7-(19)| = |-12| = -(-12) = 12$$
using  the rule above.

Hence the values of $y$ that satisfy equation $(1)$ are $-5$ and $19$.

So although $y = 19$ gives $|-12|$, it still satisfies equation $(1)$ since we take the absolute value: since $-12<0$, we have that $|-12| = -(-12) = 12.$

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes I didn't notice when the question said the answer could have both 12, and -12 it was not using absolute value bars, and was just referring to how the variable can be both positive, and negative. This answer my question!

Comment: I'm glad you got it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

$7-y=12$ or $7-y=-12$

$y=-5$ or $y=19$

If $y=-5$ then $|7-(-5)|=|12|=12$ and if $y=19$, then $|7-19|=|-12|=12$

Answer (score 0):

$|7-y|=12$ means that the distance (as you point out, this distance can only be nonnegative) between 7 and y is 12. Now, in $\mathbb{R}$ (the space of real numbers), there are two values of $y$ that are 12 units distant from 7. One of them is 12 + 7 = 19, while the other is -12 + 7 = -5.

Even though you have not asked for this in your OP, if we are talking about points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and consider the "7" to be (7,0), the equation corresponds to the points on a circle centered at (7,0) with radius 12. In this case, there will be infinite number of solutions to this equation.

Answer (score 0):

> Even if the answer inside the vertical bars was negative, wouldn't the vertical bars make it positive, resulting in just 1 positive answer?

The vertical bars are there to express a *property* you want your $y$ to have. They don't influence what $y$ itself is.

A solution to the equation means the value of the $y$ you *start* your computation with, *before* subtracting it from $7$ and positivising the result. Both of those things happen *during* the calculation you want to work, but doing them doesn't change the fact that the $y$ you started out with might have been $-5$.